# Pythonic way to set up property in Bridge design pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm trying to build a module using the "Bridge" design pattern to decouple an abstraction from its implementation. I also need a property `try_limit` that can be changed dynamically when running.

After some trial and error I wrote `bridge.py`, which works as I expected, but I need to write the property and setter twice, in `Abstraction` and `Implementor` class respectively. Is there another pythonic way to do this?

`bridge.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import abc

class Abstraction(object):
    def __init__(self, imp):
        self._imp = imp

    @property
    def try_limit(self):
        return self._imp.try_limit

    @try_limit.setter
    def try_limit(self, value):
        self._imp.try_limit = value

    def run(self, cmd):
        ret = self._imp.run(cmd)

        return ret


class Implementor(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self._try_limit = 0

    @property
    def try_limit(self):
        return self._try_limit

    @try_limit.setter
    def try_limit(self, value):
        self._try_limit = value

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self, cmd):
        pass        


class ImpA(Implementor):
    def __init__(self, realtime_display=False):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, arg):
    # Implement A which use try_limit
    # try_limit can be changed dynamically when running 


class ImpB(Implementor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, arg):
    # Implement B which also use try_limit
    # try_limit can be changed dynamically when running
```

Environment: Python 3.6.3

Comment: Have you seen this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern#Python

Comment: No, I use examples here: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge/python/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading wiki links provided by Joe, I found that I can just delete property `try_limit` in `Implementor` class because I already set `try_limit` to instance '_imp' directly. Thanks Joe & Jonrsharpe's response to my question.

`bridge_revised.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import abc

class Abstraction(object):
    def __init__(self, imp):
        self._imp = imp

    @property
    def try_limit(self):
        return self._imp.try_limit

    @try_limit.setter
    def try_limit(self, value):
        self._imp.try_limit = value

    def run(self, cmd):
        ret = self._imp.run(cmd)

        return ret


class Implementor(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.try_limit = 0

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self, cmd):
        pass        


class ImpA(Implementor):
    def __init__(self, realtime_display=False):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, arg):
    # Implement A which use try_limit
    # try_limit can be changed dynamically when running 


class ImpB(Implementor):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, arg):
    # Implement B which also use try_limit
    # try_limit can be changed dynamically when running
```

Environment: Python 3.6.3